# Parsing fails in a big JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have a big JSON file with ~220k records with a size of 223MB. I can open the JSON with a program called Huge JSON Viewew, which means that the file is well structured, but when it comes to parsing it shows a error.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const rawdata = fs.readFileSync("jsonFile.json");
let inproceedings = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

The error it shows:

```
undefined:1
��[
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DATA\script\jsonFile.js:6:26)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DATA\script>
```

Comment: It's possible your file has a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which you are not expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you readFile it reads as a buffer. use `utf-8` encoding when reading
[ https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options ]

```
const rawdata = fs.readFileSync("jsonFile.json",{encoding: 'utf-8'});
let inproceedings = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, I am still getting the same error!

Comment: I also have another file with ~110k records, and I am able to parse it without a problem.

Comment: can you console.log(rawdata) and see if it actually a JSON string ?

Comment: I am getting those two strange characters in the beginning ��. I checked the JSON file and they are nowhere there. I could just remove those two first characters from the rawdata, but I am really curious how did they end up there!